# How to mass-reset the owner of registry keys?

Tags: windows, access-control-list, windows-registry

After installing Crystal Reports 8 on a Windows Server 2008 machine, many ActiveX related keys have no owner set and thus it is impossible to register certain ActiveX controls on that machine ever again. (This is a known problem)

Is it possible to automatically assign an owner (=Administrator) to all registry keys which don't already have an owner?

If that is not possible, can I just set the owner to Administrator to *all* keys without running into problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SetACL](http://setacl.sourceforge.net) tool is a good permissions "Swiss army knife". You can use it to set registry ownership. (AFAIK, a registry key can't have "no owner". It sounds like the permissions are set such that you just don't have permission to *see* the owner. Regardless, SetACL can reset the permissions.)

The command-line is a bit obtuse, but play around with it for a bit and you'll figure it out. The [usage examples](http://setacl.sourceforge.net/html/examples.html) page for SetACL is very helpul.